# Passive WiFi detection system using WiFi router

Tags: router, sniffing, wifi

As part of my project requirement I want to make a system which will detect all the WiFi devices in my router range either its connected or not, I did some research on it then I found something like wireshark ,kismate etc I just tried the wireshark by making my Mac machine's WiFi as an adhoc network and its all fine I am able to list all the WiFi  devices in wireshark, now I want to make a real-time system based on a real WiFi router I don't know how I will configure my router using my PC and how I will monitor the router from my PC , one more thing if I am using this wireshark how I will use this data for my requirement. If any one worked with similar scenarios please help me..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you will need more than the usual API that you have on commercial WiFi routers (by that I mean a full SSH access). I would:

1. flash my router with [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) (you can search for your router on [this page](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) for detailed instructions)
2. Install the [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/) suite on the flashed router with

   ```
   opkg update
   opkg install aircrack-ng
   ```
3. Put my WiFi card in monitor mode and run the airodump service:

   ```
   airmon-ng start wlan0  #Put your NIC in monitor mode
   airodump-ng mon0       #Sniff surrounding packets
   ```

You don't necessarily have to install aircrack-ng, you can just put your card in monitor mode using command line (look at the documentation for your WiFi driver) and then run tcpdump (command line equivalent to wireshark) but aircrack works very well and has a nice format.

Also, I should warn you that you can brick your router by flashing it. I never had such a problem when flashing router mentioned on the OpenWRT wiki and there are (most of the times) ways to restore a bricked router depending on the brand but I am not responsible if you break it ;)